# Is it possible to allow to use linux kernel module only for one process ?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I have linux kernel module, which get some info from user space application via device file and return some other data.

```
int *g_GlobalVariable;

static ssize_t dev_write(struct file* file, const char __user* buffer, size_t count, loff_t* pos)
{
   int i;
   int some_size = 10000;
   char dev_buffer[64];
   copy_from_user(dev_buffer, buffer, count);
   g_GlobalVariable = kmalloc(kmalloc(some_size * sizeof(int), GFP_KERNEL);
   for(i = 0; i < some_size; i++)
   {
      g_GlobalVariable[i] = 45; //any info
   }
}
```

when user space application reads from device file, driver executes function dev_read.

```
static ssize_t dev_read(struct file* filep, char* buffer, size_t len, loff_t* offset)
{
    //do something with g_GlobalVariable
}
```

I was thinking, that it is possible situation, that two or more processes use this driver and bad things can happen, for example:

1) first process pass data via device file and function dev_write generated and filled array g_GlobalVariable

2) first process read from device file, dev_read invoked and it works with g_GlobalVariable

3) second process writes into the same device file and g_GlobalVariable contains after that other information.

4) first process in dev_read get the wrong data, or read memory, which already doesn't exist.

How can I fix this situation ?

Comment: Of course it's possible. That's why there are various locking mechanisms to prevent such problems. You'll need to use them. In this case, I'd look for a read/write lock of some kind - more than one process can *read* your data, but only one writer can write at a time. And you do need to really think about what you're doing with a kernel module. Think about, "How can I recover my system if I mess my module up so badly my system won't boot?"  Because you will do just that eventually. And **validate all inputs** - `copy_from_user(dev_buffer, buffer, count);` looks like a possible buffer overflow.

Comment: You need to protect the global variables with appropriate locking mechanism.

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer. I have idea: lock mutex at the beginning in dev_write function  and unlock it in dev_read function at the end, where global variable will not be needed. Is it okay?

Comment: @Vcvv - No! You should lock the shared data before accessing it and should be released as soon as you're done with it. Something like below:                                                                                                           
      `lock();
      // do things with global data
     unlock();`

Comment: Remember that *you are protecting **data**, and not the code*!